# How can I get random documents with the field starting letters (A to Z) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm trying to make an aggregate with mongodb. My goal is that I want to get random names
starting with letters A to Z. As a result, each word starts with letter must be only once in the response but I can't figure out how to do it. I used **match** condition *with regex* and **sample** condition to get random documents.

Here is my collection;

```
[
  {
    "name": "ahmet"
  },
  {
    "name": "barış"
  },
  {
    "name": "ceyhun"
  },
  {
    "name": "aslan"
  },
  {
    "name": "deniz"
  },
  ....
]
```

Here is my aggregate function;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: {
        $regex: "^a|^b|^c" // must be A to Z
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 3 // Must be 26
    }
  }
])
```

I'm waiting response to be like this;

```
[
  {
    "name": "ahmet"
  },
  {
    "name": "barış"
  },
  {
    "name": "ceyhun"
  },
  .... // other words starting with d, e , f but only one word for each letter
]
```

But I'm getting;

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "name": "barış"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "name": "aslan"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "ahmet"
  },
  // name => aslan, name => ahmet (Two words starting with same letter)
]
```

I'm newbie at mongodb and if anyone can help me where I'm wrong, I'll be appreciate.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0RKvP1j97fL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**Edit** with guard improvement suggestions* (using `$substrCP`, `$ifNull`):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {$substrCP: ["$name", 0, 1]},
      name: {$push: "$name"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {_id: 0,
      name: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
            "$name", 
            {$toInt: {$multiply: [{$rand: {}}, {$size: {$ifNull: ["$name",[]] }}]}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XzYnCQ98tI9).

The `$group` will keep a list of names per each `firstL`, the `$arryElemAt` with the `$rand` will keep only a random item.

*Thanks to @Mbay and @Paul for the improvement suggestions

Comment: Hi @nimrod serok,  this solution does not randomly return the names. It always brings up the first option for each letter. For example it always gets { name: "ahmet } for letter 'a'.

Comment: It is now - after my edit:)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it now works as I expected. Good job! @nimrod

Comment: My coworker and I have been playing with your playground example and love your solution!  One suggestion: even though the questions specifies `[A-Z]` there is nothing in the query that enforces that.  I would change `$substr` to `$substrCP` as a defensive measure in case a name starts with a multi-byte codepoint (like `ı` or `ş` in the original example).   cc: @Mbay

Comment: Yes @Paul, I changed $substr to $substrCP to prevent invalid range error which i faced. I also added to $ifNull operator to $size because of 'The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing'. error.  https://mongoplayground.net/p/l_csn4_S-c3